# Python nested comprehension with if statement that does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem here is that if da = 'Dagger' then the code works as expected and returns odd. If da = 'Dager', bad input, then it does not print even and b prints an empty list. Why?

```
we = [
    ["Dagger",           250,    None,   None,   200,    10,     None],
    ["Folding Stock",    500,    None,   None,   -300,   100,    None]]

da = "Dager"
print( da, we)
print()
weapon = [a for a in we if da in a]
print(weapon)
b = ["Even" if a == [] else "Odd" for a in we if da in a]

print('end', weapon, b)
```

run with bad "dager" input

```
Dager [['''big edit here'''

[]
[]
end [] []
```

run with good "Dagger" input

```
[['Dagger', 250, None, None, 200, 10, None]]
['Odd']
end [['Dagger', 250, None, None, 200, 10, None]] ['Odd']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: added some output so everyone can see how it does not output ['Even']

Answer (score 1):

It's because the way you wrote you list comprehension. You're omitting the case if the weapon is not in inventory so to say.

The correct structure is :

```
[ expression if conditional else other thing if conditional2 for this many times ]
```

Your code:

```
b = ["Even" if a == [] else "Odd" for a in we if da in a]
```

appends `"Even"` `if a == []`
        `"Odd"`  `for each a in we if da in a` | incorrect!

Should be `"Odd" if da in a for each a in we` !the for covers "even" case too.

Try with this:

```
b = ["Even" if a == [] else "Odd" if da in a else 'not' for a in we]
```

Comment: Your answer return a huge (len of list) list of 'not's" and if the Dagger was there one of the nots was "dagger".

I want it to return a sublist that starts with dagger or a value like False or a string to indicate this.

Comment: Let me understand it, if `da` is `Dagger` you want only the sublist from `we` (with `Dagger`) to appear, if `da` is 'dager` you want to return just one `False`. Is that corect?

Answer (score 1):

It's not outputting what you expect because of the order in which the different parts of the list comprehensions execute.

`[a for a in we if da in a]`

The line above makes a list of items based on the items in `we`. The list only includes the items that have `da` in them. If `da` is "Dagger", then the list returned contains one item, because one item in `we` contains the string "Dagger". If `da` is "Dager", then the list contains 0 items, because "Dager" is not present in any item of `we`.

The second list comprehension works similarly, but applies an extra step **after** the initial filtering.

`["Even" if a == [] else "Odd" for a in we if da in a]`

This part - `"Even" if a == [] else "Odd"` only runs for each item that passes the filter - `if da in a`. Because no items pass the filter for "Dager", the even/odd section is never run, resulting in an empty list.

Comment: Now that I have slept, I see that you are on the heart of the question. The if is not triggered by bad  "dager", input.

So in other words is it not ONLY after but ONLY IF there is output from the filter!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with comprehension. You said if da='Dager' then b is empty, that is expected.

Try the following and figure out why python does that

```
print('Dagger' in ["Dagger", 250, None, None, 200, 10, None])
print('Dager' in ["Dagger", 250, None, None, 200, 10, None])
```

The first one prints True because 'Dagger' == 'Dagger'

The second one prints False because 'Dager' != 'Dagger'

If you want python to disregard the amount of 'g's in 'Dagger', you need regex.

Besides, doing nested if in comprehension is a bad idea, it lacks readability. Try filter instead

```
result = ['odd' if item else 'even'
          for item in filter(lambda item: da in item, weapons)]
```

result is only going to contain 'odd' because item will always at least contain da, which makes the 'if item' always True.

If you want to turn those nested list to 'odd' if contains da, you should use map

```
result = list(map(lambda item: 'odd' if da in item else 'even', weapons))
```

---

Update: return an error if the weapon is not in the list and the sublist

That's even easier, you can use just any

```
def check_dagger(da, weapons):
    # this will return True if any sublist within weapons contains da
    # if you want to modify so that all sublist need to have da, use all
    return 'good' if any([da in item for item in weapons]) else 'error'
    # or you can raise an exception 
    if not any([da in item for item in weapons]):
        raise ValueError(f'{da} not in weapons')
```

Comment: result is only going to contain 'odd' because item will always at least consist 'Dagger

Comment: Thanks but what I want to really do is return an error if the weapon is not in the list and the sublist, if it is.

Comment: This is sort of where I started.
One line to find out if dagger was a valid input and one line to return the dagger substring when the input was correct. I was attempting to make it one line.
My one line works if the input is correct but when it is not it returns and empty list but the if statement does not react to the empty list and I don't understand that, especially because the if statement does react to the correct input.

Comment: don't do nested if statements in comprehension, do a filter after comprehension can achieve the same result with much better readability